# install missing *.sty for tint package

Tags: r, tint, tinytex

I have installed the `tint_0.1.1` package and also have a working version of `tinytex_0.11` in R (v3.5.3). I am attempting to use the supplied template -  (Tint is not Tufte (PDF)) from the File > New File > RMarkdown > From Template menu in RStudio (v1.1.383).

When I try to compile the template (Using the 'Knit' button) I get the following error message:

---

tlmgr search --file --global "/roboto.sty"
TeX Live 2018 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
Trying to automatically install missing LaTeX packages...
tlmgr install roboto
TeX Live 2018 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.

## tlmgr.pl: package repository http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)

tlmgr itself needs to be updated.
Please do this via either
  tlmgr update --self
or by getting the latest updater for Unix-ish systems:
  http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
and/or Windows systems:
  http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.exe

## Then continue with other updates as usual.

tlmgr.pl: Terminating; please see warning above!
tlmgr search --file --global "/roboto.sty"
TeX Live 2018 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
! LaTeX Error: File `roboto.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.

Error: Failed to compile tint.test2.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See tint.test2.log for more info.
Execution halted

---

I have tried using some of the `tinytex` functions (e.g. `parse_packages(), tlmgr_install and tlmgr_search()`) to workaround this issue with the `roboto.sty` but to no avail. Suggestions, help and pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Oh deary me. This took me sometime to eventually reach a solution (i.e. get *.pdf output from the `tint::tintPdf` vignette (as an `*.Rmd` file). The long and short of it was that I had already installed the `tinytex` package but had not run the second command in the following block:

`install.packages('tinytex')
tinytex::install_tinytex()`

This confused the hell out of me for a while. Further information concerning the `tinytex` package can be found here:
https://yihui.name/tinytex/

Once installed and `Kint`ing the vignette the `tlmgr` package did it's job and found the `roboto.sty` required for rendering the *.pdf